# How To Update A Large JSON file With Millions Of Data - Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api

I created a Node.js script that consumes an API that returns paginated user data as JSON. This JSON data is stored locally on my computer in a JSON file.

Currently I store all the pagination data returned into Ram and then write the data to a JSON file. The reason I'm using JSON file is because it will be used in another program by a client for statistical purposes.

But my concern is that one of the endpoint has about millions of user data that storing everything in the Ram can lead to memory issues, so I want to be able to push the data to a JSON file as I receive the paginated data.

Example of JSON data in file

Filename: **users.json**

```
[{username: blah, id: 4847585, items: Array[]},
...
{username: foo, id: 1204855, items: Array[]}
]
```

where `...` indicates about millions of other user data.

How can I push user data to the **users.json** file **without** loading the millions of user data into Ram then parsing then updating (push) then stringfying and then finally writing it back to the **users.json** file?

Comment: *"This JSON data is stored locally on my computer in a JSON file."* - That's the point you need to change. Use a database. JSON is not a database, JSON is a data transfer format.

Comment: You could just remove last `]`, insert a comma and your new stringified object, and insert back the `]`. Or use some JSON line format. Or change to SQLite?

Comment: @cbr I would still have to load millions of the data into Ram

Comment: Just open the file with `fs.open` and use `fs.write` with an offset to overwrite the last `]`. No need to parse or read the entire file if you just want to append to it.

Comment: @cbr I checked the node docs on how to use the fs.open and fs.write, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to use it with an offset to overwrite the ```]``` Could you kindly give an example of how to append with an offset?

Comment: Use. a. database. Storing "millions of records" in JSON is wrong, and all the problems you have are due to you using the wrong solution to a very simple problem. The right way to solve this is not "clever file manipulation", the right way to solve this is to start using a tool that was made for the purpose of storing and manipulating millions of rows efficiently.